# Excel Cumulative Sum with Reset on Target Sum

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking a for a simple formula to calculating a running sum on a column and resetting the sum when it reaches/crosses a target sum.

eg:
Target 35

| A | RC |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 12 |
| 6 | 18 |
| 10 | 28 |
| 8 | 8 |
| 20 | 28 |
| 10 | 10 |

Tried mod() but not sure how to restart the counter, any other simple solution?

Answer (score 5):

Check if the sum would be greater than the limit if so, then put in the value, other wise sum:

```
=IF(SUM(B1,A2)>$E$1,A2,SUM(B1,A2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using `SCAN` you could spill the result:

`=SCAN(0,A1:A6,LAMBDA(a,b,LET(c,a+b,IF(c<=35,c,b))))`

Or similar, but shorter: `=SCAN(0,A1:A6,LAMBDA(a,b,b+(a+b<=35)*a))`

[image]